# Change the grid points of parametric splines in Matlab

Tags: matlab, grid, coordinates, spline, piecewise

**My Code right now**

```
% Create some example points x and y
t = pi*[0:.05:1,1.1,1.2:.02:2]; a = 3/2*sqrt(2);
for i=1:size(t,2)
    x(i) = a*sqrt(2)*cos(t(i))/(sin(t(i)).^2+1);
    y(i) = a*sqrt(2)*cos(t(i))*sin(t(i))/(sin(t(i))^2+1);
end
```

Please note: The points (x_i|y_i) are not necessarily equidistant, that's why t is created like this. Also t should not be used in further code as for my real problems it is not known, I just get a bunch of x, y and z values in the end. For this example I reduced it to 2D.

Now I'm creating ParametricSplines for the x and y values

```
% Spline 
n=100; [x_t, y_t, tt] = ParametricSpline(x, y, n); 
xref = ppval(x_t, tt); yref = ppval(y_t, tt);
```

with the function

```
function [ x_t, y_t, t_t ] = ParametricSpline(x,y,n) 
  m = length(x); 
  t = zeros(m, 1); 
  for i=2:m 
    arc_length = sqrt((x(i)-x(i-1))^2 + (y(i)-y(i-1))^2); 
    t(i) = t(i-1) + arc_length; 
  end
  t=t./t(length(t)); 
  x_t = spline(t, x); 
  y_t = spline(t, y); 
  t_t = linspace(0,1,n); 
end
```

The plot generated by

```
plot(x,y,'ob',...
    xref,yref,'xk',...
    xref,yref,'-r'),...
    axis equal;
```

looks like the follows: [Plot Spline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47CnE.png)

**The Question:**

How do I change the code so I always have one of the resulting points `(xref_i|yref_i)` (shown as Black X in the plot) directly on the originally given points `(x_j|y_j)` (shown as Blue O) with additionally n points between `(x_j|y_j)` and `(x_j+1|y_j+1)`?

E.g. with n=2 I would like to get the following:

```
(xref_1|yref_1) = (x_1|y_1)
(xref_2|yref_2)
(xref_3|yref_3)
(xref_4|yref_4) = (x_2|y_2)
(xref_5|yref_5)
[...]
```

I guess the only thing I need is to change the definition of `tt` but I just can't figure out how... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as your function:

```
function [ x_t, y_t, tt ] = ParametricSpline(x,y,nt) 

arc_length = 0; 
n = length(x); 
t = zeros(n, 1);

mul_p = linspace(0,1,nt+2)';
mul_p = mul_p(2:end);
tt = t(1);

for i=2:n 
    arc_length = sqrt((x(i)-x(i-1))^2 + (y(i)-y(i-1))^2); 
    t(i) = t(i-1) + arc_length;
    add_points = mul_p * arc_length + t(i-1);
    tt = [tt ; add_points];  
end

t=t./t(end);
tt = tt./tt(end);
x_t = spline(t, x); 
y_t = spline(t, y); 

end
```

The essence:
You have to construct tt in the same way as your distance vector t plus add additional nt points in between.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. :)